# Odd behavior with date_sub and DateIntervals

Tags: php, datetime

My ultimate goal was to subtract 1 minute from the current time, but while learning how that works, I hit this odd behavior.  The code:

```
$curdate=date_create();
echo "Current date: " . date_format($curdate, "Y-m-d H:m:s") . "<br />";
$duration = new DateInterval("P3D");
print_r($duration);
echo '<br />';
$olderdate = date_sub($curdate,new DateInterval("P3D"));
echo "Fixed up Date " . date_format($olderdate,"Y-m-d H:m:s") . "<br />";
$evenolderdate = date_sub($curdate,$duration);
echo "Even Older Fixed up Date " . date_format($evenolderdate,"Y-m-d H:m:s");
```

And the results:

```
Current date: 2021-10-01 16:10:18
Fixed up Date 2021-09-28 16:09:18
Even Older Fixed up Date 2021-09-25 16:09:18 

DateInterval Object ( [y] => 0 
    [m] => 0 
    [d] => 3 
    [h] => 0 
    [i] => 0 
    [s] => 0 
    [f] => 0 
    [weekday] => 0 
    [weekday_behavior] => 0 
    [first_last_day_of] => 0 
    [invert] => 0 
    [days] => 
        [special_type] => 0 
        [special_amount] => 0 
        [have_weekday_relative] => 0 
        [have_special_relative] => 0 )
```

Why are the results of the date_sub off by a minute?  And if I change the interval format to P3M, it'll be off by 3 minutes.

Comment: Format `H:m:s` is showing the month where the minutes should be.

Comment: It should be `H:i:s`

Comment: Thank you.  PEBCAK.

Comment: What clued me in was that the minute in the current time was always 10, no matter when I ran the script.